# Symfony-cmf routing step by step

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

The symfony-cmf documentation is a nightmare, it is really hard to understand and it seems that many of it is outdated.

I think I have understood the routing concept, but I can't figure how to implement it, clearly.

1. How to register a router?
2. How to setup dynamic routing?
3. How to persist a document and map a route?

Answer (score 2):

FYI 1.1 was been released and the documentation has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to hear that. If you run on 1.0, things should not be outdated, except for some cookbook entries which have a note at their head. The 1.1 documentation is not online yet as we currently can only publish one version of the doc. That is only available on [github](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf-docs/tree/dev).

Your questions however are answered by both versions:

1. http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/routing/introduction.html#loading-routers-with-tagging
2. http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic.html - also the [sandbox](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox) is a good example to see this in action
3. http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic.html#the-phpcr-odm-route-document

If you have inputs how we can make it easier to find the way through the doc or at which point in the quick tour / book you got lost, please open issues (or even better pull requests) on the symfony-cmf-docs github repository.

Comment: Thank you David, I've already read this doc and I miss something more concrete, like this one http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/cookbook/creating_a_cms/index.html
I would be very glad to contribute to this project, as soon as I will be able to do so ;)